# Unable to change width and height of vuejs-datepicker

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs-datepicker

I looked into this [vuejs-datepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuejs-datepicker) to add datepicker to my project.

```
<div class="startDate">
    <datepicker
     v-model="startDate"
     format="YYYY-MM-DD"
     name="startDate"
     ></datepicker>
</div>
```

> import datepicker from "vue-date-picker";

```
<style scoped>
  .startDate {
   width: 150px;
   }
<style>
```

But still width of **startDate** shows **238px** which is default width of datepicker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all remove **scoped** from **style** portion. And obtain *classname* by **inspecting** datepicker element.

> Here, in my case classname for startDate is **.datetime-picker
>   input[data-v-a46a390c]**

Now, apply to css like this:

```
.datetime-picker input[data-v-a46a390c] {
  width: 150px;
  height: 38px;
}
```

Comment: This worked for me : .dp__input_icon_pad
{
  height: 33px;
}

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
<div>
    <datepicker class="startDate"
        v-model="startDate"
        :readonly="true"
        format="YYYY-MM-DD"
        name="startDate"
     ></datepicker>
</div>
```

```
 .startDate {
    width: 150px;
     }
```

Comment: I tried this already. It didn't work either. I think there may be issue with vuejs-datepicker.

Comment: add !important sign

Comment: I have found the solution and posted above. Check it !!! Thanks for ur help too !!!

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove scoped from my component and then I was able to use this to change background color of selected date.

```
    .cell.day.selected{
      background: green !important;
    }
```

So like this you can override any styles of vuejs-datepicker. like below:

```
`.cell.day.selected {
background: $blue !important;
}
.cell.day-header,
.day__month_btn.up {
font-weight: bold !important;
}
.vdp-datepicker input[type="text"]:read-only {
 width: 200px;
 cursor: pointer;
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

when trying to style the input of a vuejs-datepicker component, try using the input-class attribute:

`<datepicker input-class="focus:outline-none"></datepicker>`